# DB2 updated rows since last check

Tags: db2, rdbms

I want to periodically export data from db2 and load it in another database for analysis.
In order to do this, I would need to know which rows have been inserted/updated since the last time I've exported things from a given table.

A simple solution would probably be to add a timestamp to every table and use that as a reference, but I don't have such a TS at the moment, and I would like to avoid adding it if possible.

Is there any other solution for finding the rows which have been added/updated after a given time (or something else that would solve my issue)?

Comment: Do more research on synchronising tables. Different solutions exist depending on your Db2-server platform and version, the target RDBMS type and version and platform, and what toolset you have available. Solutions include CDC/QREP/SQLREP, or third party tools for synching tables. Or you can re-invent a wheel.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy option for a timestamp in Db2 (for LUW) called

> ROW CHANGE TIMESTAMP

This is managed by Db2 and could be defined as HIDDEN so existing SELECT * FROM queries will not retrieve the new row which would cause extra costs.

Check out the [Db2 CREATE TABLE documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000927.html)

This functionality was originally added for optimistic locking but can be used for such situations as well.

There is a similar concept for Db2 z/OS - you have to check that out as I have not tried this one.

Of cause there are other ways to solve it like Replication etc.

Comment: this sounds nice. I will try it. Thanks!

Comment: Its same on Z/OS as well.

LAST_UPDT_TS TIMESTAMP NOT NULL 
  GENERATED ALWAYS 
  FOR EACH ROW ON UPDATE AS ROW CHANGE TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible if you do not have a timestamp column. With a timestamp, you can know which are new or modified rows.

You can also use the TimeTravel feature, in order to get the new values, but that implies a timestamp column.

Another option, is to put the tables in append mode, and then get the rows after a given one. However, this option is not sure after a reorg, and affects the performance and space utilisation.

One possible option is to use SQL replication, but that needs extra tables for staging.

Finally, another option is to read the logs, with the db2ReadLog API, but that implies a development. Also, just appliying the archived logs into the new database is possible, however the database will remain in roll forward pending.